# Can bellows make loops?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, polyhedra

Can flexible polyhedron (hyperbolic or euclidean) have non-simply connected configuration space not containing singular polyhedra?

Comment: Could you explain what the phrase "singular polyhedra" means? Thanks.

Comment: Ones with angles between faces equal to $0$ or $\pi$. Without excluding that things you can easily find examples in $1$-dim polyhedra.